# Argument in Fragment null in onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, serializable

Within my `Activity` I begin the `FragmentTransaction` and set an `Argument` to my `Fragment`.

```
DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT, navigate.product);
detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Within my `Fragment`s class I override the setArgument method and parse the `Serializable` object:

```
Product product;

@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);

    product = (Product) args.getSerializable(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT);
}
```

All of this is working fine, but as soon as I am debugging within my `onCreateView()` method, the previously set product is `null`. Can somebody explain this to me? And what is the correct approach to do this?

**EDIT:**

Following the answer by Michael I ended up with the following pieces of code:
In the `Activity`:

```
DetailFragment detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(navigate.product);
```

And in the Fragment:

```
 public static DetailFragment newInstance(Product product) {
        DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT, product);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

But when I try to access the `getArgument()` within `onCreate()` it will give `null`:

```
if (getArguments() != null) {
     product = (Product) getArguments().getSerializable(Constants.KEY_PRODUCT);
}
```

and my `Product` is never set. Did I miss something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `getArguments` in `onCreate`.

If you look at the generated code when adding a new fragment to your project in Android Studio:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;


public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

}
```

The arguments are set in the fragments constructor and are pulled back out in `onCreate` since `onCreate` is called befre `onCreateView` in the fragment lifecycle you will be able to access these arguments in `onCreateView` and later.

Comment: What's the reason, that `product` is being `null`ed out when it has been initialized in `setArguments()`?

Comment: @azizbekian it is being `null`ed out because the `Fragment` hasn't been added to the `FragmentManager` yet and the `FragmentManager` can kill and recreate fragments with states that is why we need to use arguments and not a constructor, in this case setting the `product` in `setArguments()` is no different to using a constructor, but you will still have the `product` in the `Bundle` that `getArguments()` returns.

Comment: @Kostyantin2216, I get the point of get/set argument. The question that I couldn't answer on, is why that fragment is being `null`ed out, because it hadn't yet been destroyed by the system. If this was a scenario, when system kills the process, and user navigates back - then it is fine, `product` field should be null, but otherwise I cannot see(even in sources) how and where that `Bundle` is being `null`ed out.

Comment: @azizbekian But you cen recreate my issue? 
@Kostyantin2216 But why are those parameters set in the `newInstance()` method, I would like to retreive them?

Comment: @MichaelStoddart Okay, I tried this approach now, but `getArguments()` delivers `null` within `onCerate()` as well. So the basic idea here is to pass the Object with the `newInstance()` methods, instead of using the `setArguments()` from the `Activity`.

Comment: Exactly @4ndro1d, you would call the fragment in your activity like so:  FragmentTransaction transaction = fragMan.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, BlankFragment.newInstance("param1", "param2"));
        transaction.addToBackStack("TAG");
        transaction.commit();

Comment: @4ndro1d put your Product class in the question as well please

Comment: @MichaelStoddart It is a GSON annotated class, with fields, getters and setters, nothing more. And ofc it implements `Serializable`. When debugging the `newInstance()` method the arguments holds all the necessary parameters.

Comment: @4ndro1d have you checked that navigate.product isnt null?

Comment: Yes, as I said even in the `newInstance()` method the parameters of my `Product` are set correctly into the `Arguments` object

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. The problem with my code was that the Arguments were being set twice (bundle.setArguments()) - once from the activity and again during fragment launch where I was sending it inside newInstance() and doing bundle.setArguments() again. What happens is, the arguments get overwritten and the data that is got in bundle is lost by the time the flow comes inside onCreate() or onCreateView().

Hope this helps. :)